# Como retornar a pagina com o "anchor" do id LARAVEL?

Tags: php, laravel, url, bootstrap, id

Após submeter o formulário eu retorno para a página em questão com dois métodos, `redirect()` e `back()`. No caso estou usando as *tabs do bootstrap* e gostaria de voltar com a âncora do id, ex:

```
return redirect()->back();  // #menu1 ??
```

> Nota* passando o metodo with() ele não identa na url

Comment: Pode incluir o codigo bootstrap sff.. Pelo menos o das tabs, para ver as classes. É isto a que se refere? http://jsfiddle.net/xfw8t/12/

Comment: Sim, gostaria de voltar na tab correspondente

Comment: Feito em baixo @Igor, acho que assim é o melhor para o que quer fazer

Answer (score 4):

Se concatenar ao url anterior é o que quer basta :

```
$urlBack = redirect()->back()->getTargetUrl();
return redirect($urlBack. '#menu1');
```

Testado em laravel 5.1 e 5.2

Versão 5.3 e 5.4 podemos fazer só:

```
return redirect(url()->previous(). '#menu1');
```

Depois basta no js:

```
var tab_on = location.hash; // #menu1
$('#ulTabs a[data-target="' +tab_on+ '"]').tab('show'); // ajustar seletor (#ulTabs...) ao seu caso
```

Comment: Valeu, obrigado Miguel!

Answer (score 0):

Quando você utiliza o método `back()`, ele faz o uso da classe UrlGenerator, para ser mais específico, o método `previous()`:

```
/**
 * Get the URL for the previous request.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function previous()
{
    $referrer = $this->request->headers->get('referer');

    $url = $referrer ? $this->to($referrer) : $this->getPreviousUrlFromSession();

    return $url ?: $this->to('/');
}
```

Este método valida e faz a remoção dos parametros da url antes de retorna-la, através do método `to()` dessa mesma classe.

Levando isso em consideração, se utilizar-mos a primeira linha deste método, vamos receber por exemplo, algo do tipo:

> http://localhost:8000/user?id=1&name=Rafael

Se você juntar isso com o método `redirect()`, você vai retornar para a mesma url anterior, incluindo seus parâmetros. Por exemplo:

```
...

public function index()
{
    // the previous url with the old params.
    $url = request()->headers->get('referer');

    return redirect($url);
}

...
```